# Access to url forbidden error while checkout using pysvn

Tags: python, svn, pysvn, python-3.5

This is my code,

```
import pysvn
def get_login( realm, username, may_save ):
    print(username)
    print(password)
    return True, username, password, False
client = pysvn.Client()
username="abcd"
password="xyz"
client.set_default_username( username )
client.set_default_password( password )
client.callback_get_login = get_login
#check out the current version of the pysvn project
client.checkout('http://svn.source.com/svn/module', 'D:\pysvn')
```

While I run this code it throws this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "123.py", line 13, in 
>       client.checkout('http://svn.source.com/svn/module', 'D:\pysvn')
>   pysvn._pysvn_3_5.ClientError: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.source.com/svn/module'
>   Access to '/svn/module' forbidden

I tried with and without using set_default_username and password.
Both of them giving same error.
Actually why this error coming.Can anyone of pySVN expert here able to  explain this?

Comment: Is there a valid user "abcd" with password "xyz" registered?

Comment: And in case of path-based auth. does this user have access to the requested path?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Here i changed them to abcd,123.Actually the original username and password i given in that code is the one which is used to checkout from SVN directly and it is working fine in svn.

Answer (score 1):

just try not to use get_login at all and use only:

```
    client.set_default_username( username )
    client.set_default_password( password )
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps!